# SoundEngine can not be resolved cocos2d-android-1

Tags: android, cocos2d-android

I am learning from here [link] (http://dan.clarke.name/2011/04/how-to-make-a-simple-android-game-with-cocos2d/) but I am stuck at a point where we have to use this

```
SoundEngine.sharedEngine().preloadEffect(context, R.raw.pew_pew_lei);
SoundEngine.sharedEngine().playSound(context, R.raw.background_music_aac, true);
```

there is no SoundEngine import fount. Says that SoundEngine can not be resolved. Other then SoundEngine all other functionalities are working fine. Am I missing some thing (some other library). I have added cocos2d-android-1 from here [Link] (https://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-android-1/downloads/detail?name=cocos2d-android.jar&can=2&q=) Is there some other library for SoundEngine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for bother but I have found the problem solution as I was using wrong jar file now I am using the jar file fro here [Link] (http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcocos2djar.htm)